# I cant seem to access parameters of my listed object

Tags: java, linked-list

So I have an Item class:

```
public class Item {
    public String itemName;
    public double value;
    List<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
```

with such attributes. I have added new Items to my list like this:

```
items.add(new Item(itemName:"Bread",value: 1.5));
items.add(new Item(itemName:"Water",value:1.25));
.
.
.
```

I'm trying to access the value and calculate the sum of items which I have added to my Item list.But cant figure out how. Anyone can help?

Comment: "I'm trying to access the value and calculate the sum of items which I have added to my Item list." How are you doing that? Where is the code of you trying to do that? At least try to put 0.1% of effort instead of just posting to stackoverflow. Read this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Comment: well I've tried somethings but none of them worked so I didn't post them here

Comment: Show us, what you've tried. Then we can guide you.

Comment: The main issue here in my opinion is that the list `items` is an instance variable of `Item`.

Comment: basically created a method where I could keep my sum variable then tried to access it like double sum= addedItems.get(i) and put it in a for loop such as for(int i=0;i<addedItems.size();i++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use streams:

```
double sum = items.stream().mapToDouble(i -> i.value).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

Output:

`2.75`

Alternative 1 with basic for-loop:

```
double sum2 = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
    sum2 += items.get(i).value;
}
System.out.println(sum2);
```

Alternative 2 with enhanced for-loop:

```
double sum3 = 0.0;
for(Item item : items) {
    sum3 += item.value;
}
System.out.println(sum3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:  `int v = items.get(0).value;`